# 'GameState': base class undefined

Tags: c++, class

I have a general `GameState` class:

```
#pragma once

#include "GameContext.h"

class GameContext;

class GameState
{
private:
protected:
public:
    GameState(GameContext* context);

    GameContext* gameContext = nullptr;

    virtual void update(float deltaTime) = 0;
    virtual void draw(float deltaTime) = 0;

};
```

which is suppose to be the base for other GameState's. I have attempted to implement a derived class of `GameState`:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

#include "GameState.h"
#include "GameContext.h"

class GameStateMenu : public GameState
{
private:
protected:
public:
    GameStateMenu(GameContext* gameContext);

    void update(float deltaTime);
    void draw(float deltaTime);
};
```

I am getting a error in the implementation of `GameStateMenu` at

```
class GameStateMenu : public GameState
```

where it says

> 'GameState': base class undefined

I have googled and gone through my code for a good few hours now and can still not figure it out. I feel like it should know what `GameState` is but I can't figure out why it doesn't.

(If the current code is not enough to figure it out the rest is available [HERE](https://github.com/Dequilla/Game/tree/master/Project%20Mystery))

Comment: If there is a better way to do anything in the code aswell I always appriciate constructive criticism!

Comment: I've [edited your question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40098274/2) which I hope makes it clearer, and removed some of the fluff. If you feel I have edited too much, you can always re-[edit] or rollback my edit.

Comment: No problem, much appriciated!!

Comment: FWIW: your problem [can't be reproduced](https://ideone.com/0ePjEE) when the classes are in the same file.

Comment: No, I am pretty sure it has something to do with all the dependencies among all my classes and how they interact with eachothers includes.

Comment: It may not be your issue, but in your GameState class header you are including the GameContext.h file as well as forward declaring. Just do one or the other.

Comment: I would guess you have a circular include somewhere.

Comment: Holy macarony, I thought I had try'd it already, I must've only try'd to remove the forward declaration and not remove the include. It seems to have compiled. I knew there where some funky dependencies somewhere. Will keep an eye out for things like this in the future, including is not as straight forward as it sometimes seems. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected the problem was a circular dependency that I had also forward declared which meant that I did not see an error about it when compiling. Removing the `#include "GameContext.h"` in `GameState.h` removed the one circular dependecy that was causing the problem.